# Geometry for standalone class

Tags: graphics, geometry, standalone

When using `article` class, one can specify arbitrary page size using `geometry` package.

But in `standalone` class, I can only specify the width using the `varwidth` option.

I tried using `geometry` package but that did not help.

How do I ask the `standalone` class to produce image of a particular dimensions or rather, a particular aspect ratio?

Here is why I want to achieve that. I am typesetting mostly text. Most of the times, the output produced by default works. But at times, I need to produce image of a particular aspect ratio. Also, as a side note, it would be quite OK if we can achieve the same result using some other class.

Comment: why use standalone at all in that case? The main point of standalone is to make a page that is closely fitted to the actual size of the content.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I agree. So, the last line in the question about suitability of using some other class. I still want the page closely fitted to the content. But an aspect ratio different than what standalone produces. Can I do this using, say, article?

Comment: The class you use depends on the purpose of your document. If you type text, `article` seems fine, then adjust the geometry of your page accordingly, for example, using the `geometry` package.

Comment: You can specify both the width and height (optional) for a minipage inside a standalone document.   See also  `[multi={minipage}]`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes. Thanks. `minipage` seems to be the way to go. Except that given an aspect ratio, I am not able to get `minipage` dimensions that would exactly fit the contentt. How do I ask Latex to compute them automatically?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I guess a new question on this would be more appropriate. I will ask one.